# How to add or use customized filters in PL UPLOAD API file uploads?

Tags: plupload

How to add or use customized filters in Plupload API file uploads?
I want to add validation like escaping special characters from filename while uploading ?

Answer (score 0):

They have [an example](https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/File-Filters) in their documentation. Here's how their own `max_file_size` filter looks like:

```
plupload.addFileFilter('max_file_size', function(maxSize, file, cb) {
  var undef;

  // Invalid file size
  if (file.size !== undef && maxSize && file.size > maxSize) {
    this.trigger('Error', {
      code : plupload.FILE_SIZE_ERROR,
      message : plupload.translate('File size error.'),
      file : file
    });
    cb(false);
  } else {
    cb(true);
  }
});
```

> The callback for the filter receives three arguments:
>
> - **maxSize** - *the value from the config (in the case above - 200mb)*
> - **file** - *the file object that is being filtered*
> - **cb** - *the callback which the filter must invoke once it comes up with the check result*

So you basically invoke `cb` callback with either `true` if check has passed, or `false` if it - failed.

Comment: Actually i would like add filter for file name validation if filename contains special characters than i need to throw warning .I am unable to customize the example which is given by you.please help if you any thoughts